# Payum PayPal express-checkout

Tags: paypal-rest-sdk, payum

I am using PayPal PLUS (REST/PHP SDK) and want to switch to PayPal Checkout.

Now I had a look at Payum and Omnipay. Would like to use one of them, perhaps Payum.

But, express-checkout is not the same as Checkout?
https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/docs/paypal/express-checkout/get-it-started.md
!=
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express Checkout was the name of the original API PayPal created for integrating its checkout, 15+ years ago.

There are a number of newer ways to integrate PayPal Checkout now. The best UX is to use PayPal's JS SDK, which keeps your site loaded in the background and opens a small window for payer approval, with your site still open and visible (dimmed) in the background.

Here's the frontend code to use: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server .  Your second link goes into other details about it.

As far as the backend, any of the PayPal APIs will still work, but the most current is v2/checkout/orders so a system that uses it will be the best choice, vs. the older v1/payments REST or even older "express checkout" classic nvp APIs.

I looked at what Payum has and didn't see anything for v2/checkout/orders, only the older REST and classic nvp APIs.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I am not familiar with the JS SDK and thought working along with PHP is more "appropriate" in most cases. Will see through the JS docs!

Comment: PHP (or whichever backend) should be used for the order creation and capture of course, but pairing that with the JS SDK gives an approval flow that's a nicer user experience than redirecting away from your site

Comment: Just a quick follow-up question … there are 2 fetch statements for `"/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/create/"` and `'/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/' + data.orderID + '/capture/'` … but what are those returning? Are there any examples? I don't see how I have to build the code for those routes.

Comment: There is a full stack example in node.js at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ ; you can do the same from PHP using curl or whatever

Comment: Yeah, got it! Thanks. The big picture of v2 is getting more visible :-)